# How to do real-time human segmentation in my android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, spark-ar-studio

I am new to AR and Android so I tried Human segmentation and background change with Spark AR but as we can not use Spark AR project in my android app except Facebook and Instagram and if I can integrate spark AR project in my android app then please tell me how.

Also I tried doing it with arcore by google but all android devices do not support arcore so it could not be an option.

therefore I want to have an solution on how to make a real-time human segmentation app on android which supports basic devices

if we can use ml in that ...then please show me the path

Thank You and here are some samples from my spark AR app

[image]

[image]

Comment: Were you successful in implementing the same background segmentation with Google ARCore??

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use machine learning, for example using [DeepLab](http://liangchiehchen.com/projects/DeepLab.html) with [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).